# Cannot change href attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am accessing links on a webpage with jQuery, with the following code:

```
$('a[href]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('class', 'visited');
  $(this).attr('href', '#');
})
```

The class on the link will be changed, but the href will not. Is there something preventing me from changing/altering the href?

Edit:

I updated the code to the following:

```
$('a[href]').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('visited');
        this.href = '#';
        })
```

However, although it works on MOST websites, it doesn't work on news.yahoo.com. Any reasons why this is so?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PbC8y/

Comment: This script does work on most websites: However, for example, it doesn't seem to work on http://news.yahoo.com/. I am using the updated code per @PSCoder:
    this.href ="#"

Comment: are you trying to access news.yahoo.com elements via an iframe ? this is not supposed to work

Comment: This is not supposed to work, for an even greater reason - **news.yahoo.com does NOT use jQuery**

Answer (score 3):

For the href, you probably want to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

For the classname, in most cases you want to use `.addClass()` instead of overwriting the entire class attribute.

Comment: Why use `.prop()`? This isn't something that users normally alter like `checked` or `selected`. `.attr()` is entirely correct to use in this case.

Comment: @Blazemonger - I think you are right - I stand corrected. So would it be accurate to say that either `.prop()` or `.attr()` is equally valid for this use? (Actually I like the direct DOM property reference in PSCoder's answer the best.)

Comment: It's possible to change the `checked` state of a checkbox input *without* altering the DOM -- you just click on the checkbox. In that case, `.prop()` is the correct method. However, it's impossible to change the `href` of an anchor without modifying the DOM directly in some way, so `.attr()` is the appropriate method.

Comment: Ideally, `prop` should not be used as you are not changing/toggling a property. You are modifying the `class` which is an `attribute` and hence `attr()`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use jquery wrapper over `this` to do this:- You can just access `href` as a property from `this`  itself as it represents the dom element.

```
$('a[href]').each(function() {
 ...
   this.href ="#";
})
```

Comment: But $ itself is jQuery and each a memberfunction of jQuery ;)

Comment: What he means is that you don't need to use jQuery for the line of code that sets the `href`; the direct DOM reference is as easy or easier to use. Of course you're still using jQuery for other parts of your code.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for clarifying to OlikerK. I edited my answer to make it more clear. :)